# Why does this code not set the collectionviewcontroller's view as the one visible?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class CollectionHolderViewController: MainPageContentViewController { //MainPageContentViewController inherits from UIViewController

    var collectionViewController = UICollectionViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TrophyRoom") as UICollectionViewController
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.addChildViewController(collectionViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(collectionViewController.view) //I tried collectionViewController.collectionView with no success either
        self.collectionViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

This code worked for a UIPageViewController but not for this UICollectionViewController.

I just see a blank white (default) UIViewController which is expected if the UICollectionViewController's view was NOT set. There is no error shown in XCode 6.

Help?

Edit: The code DOES in fact work : ) Just a tip, set the collectionViewController.view to have a frame that fills the screen for consistency otherwise it will fit just below the status bar.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. Did you try logging self.collectionViewController to see if it's nil?

Comment: Your comment made me realize there was a storyboard mistake, thank you for takin the time to test it !